# Retrieve Cloud Firestore data just for user Logged in Flutter application

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

What I want to do is to retrieve data from Cloud Firestore just for user Logged into the app.
I am using Auth Firebase and I built a method to retrieve some documents from a specific collection called "user" and it works and it show the right Name of the user logged and the user signed up into my form.
Now I am collecting with another form another Firestore collection called "shippingAddress" and the documents into the "shippingAddress" collection should be show into the app just for the specific user logged into the app.
but this is not happen, any user logged I got the same data from all user except name and email address.
this is my code:

```
final databaseReference = Firestore.instance;

  Future<QuerySnapshot> getData() async {
    var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    return await Firestore.instance
        .collection("user")
        .where("email", isEqualTo: firebaseUser.email)
        .getDocuments();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: getData(),
      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          return ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Stream(),
                  ],
                );
              });
        } else if (snapshot.data == null) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        }
        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
    );
  }
}

class Stream extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StreamState createState() => _StreamState();
}

class _StreamState extends State<Stream> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('shippingAddress').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
//        if (!snapshot.hasData) return Text('Loading data please Wait');
        return Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 1000,
              child: ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Card(
                    color: Color(0xFF1f2032),
                    elevation: 15,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 60,
                      height: 60,
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          
                          Text(
                            snapshot.data.documents[index]['alias'],
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

please help I am stuck into this.
here is the screenshot of my database:
[image: Screen of database]

[image: User collections]

Comment: Right now you load all shipping addresses with `stream: Firestore.instance.collection('shippingAddress').snapshots()`. You'll need to write a query that selects only the shipping addresses for the current user. If that is giving you problems, edit your question to include a screenshot of a `shippingAddress` document.

Comment: I added the database screenshot

Comment: How is the document in that screenshot related to a user? If the document ID is the user's UID, then you can do `var user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(); Firestore.instance.collection('shippingAddress').document(user.uid).snapshots()`

Comment: Ok I added user collections.

Comment: How do you know what user (in screenshot 2) the shipping address (in screenshot 1) belongs to? Firestore doesn't automatically add such relations, so if it exists somewhere it's because you added it.

Comment: By auth in firebase. If you scroll up the code you will see futurbuilder. This query retrieve the user logged. I use future builder to retrieve data from the user logged and stream builder to retrieve another collection, because with future builder I cant

Comment: Firebase does not automatically create an association between the document in `shippingAddress` and a user. For a user you *know* their email address and can use that to look up their document with `.where("email", isEqualTo: firebaseUser.email)`, since you store the user's email address in the document. You'll need to know something that is stored in each `shippingAddress` document too, to allow you to look up the shipping address(es) for a user.

Comment: At the moment my app works in this manner:
By Signup Form I create user by Firebase AUTH and create a collection in firestore called "user"
as you can see above in futurebuilder I get data from "user" collection and I show just the field collected in the "user" collection then the name of the person logged and also the email if I want.
I create another Form that allow the user logged to create a shipment to another person.

Comment: This form collect the data of another person and push these data to shippingAddress collection, what I want to to pull the shippingAddress documents and show them into a listview, that at the moment it works fine, but the problem is that every person which logged in the app see the same data except the name and the email address created into user collection.

Answer (score 1):

```
**can you share the Database image?
```

if you want specific user information you need to use this method

```
 Firestore.instance
    .collection('talks')
    .document('document-name')
    .get()
    .then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
  // use ds as a snapshot
});
```

Comment: The problem is that I cant retrieve data just for the specific user logged or assign the collection to this user.

Answer (score 0):

first of all add user id "uid" to your user model and shipping Address collection because we use it to retrieve the data (the uid has the same name of the document), and when user sign up or sends the shipping data use this method, and dont forget to add a controller to each field:

```
void signUp(String email, String password) async {
    if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      await _auth
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password)
          .then((value) => {postDataToFirestore()})
          .catchError((e) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: e!.message);
      });
    }
  }

  postDataToFirestore() async {
    //Creating Instance of firestore from firebase
    FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    User? user = _auth.currentUser;

    //Creating an instance of UserModel Class
    UserModel userModel = UserModel();

    //providing the fields values to the user model class
    userModel.uid = user!.uid;
    userModel.alias = aliasController.text;
    userModel.phoneNumber = phoneController.text;
    userModel.street = streetController.text;
    userModel.streetNumber = streetNumberController.text;
    userModel.totalQuality = totalQualityController.text;
    userModel.zipNumber = zipNumberController.text;

    //Sending data to firestore
    await firebaseFirestore
        .collection("Users")
        .doc(user.uid) //document name is the same as user id value
        .set(userModel.toMap());

    //Account Created Successfuly message
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Account Created Successfully .. :)");

    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
        (context),
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()),
        (route) => false);
  }
```

change the form fields and key according to your form. then when retrieving the data we will use the "uid" as follows:

```
 User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  UserModel loggedInUser = UserModel();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Users").doc(user!.uid).get().then(
        (value) => setState(
            () => this.loggedInUser = UserModel.fromMap(value.data())));
  }
```

then we can retrieve any data from any field as follows:

```
"${loggedInUser.alias}"
```

just change the fields name according to your need.